# Why is the keyup handler being invoked here, and can I prevent it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Consider the following HTML5+Javascript:

```js
$(function() { 
    $('#edit').hide();
 
 $('#value')
  .css('cursor', 'pointer')
  .click(function() {
   $('#edit').show();
   $('#edit input').focus();
   $('#value').hide();
  });
 
 $('#edit input')
  .keyup(function(e) {
   if (e.keyCode == 13) {  // <enter>
    $('#value').show();
    $('#edit').hide();
   }
  });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="value">
 <a href="#">hello</a>
</div>
<div id="edit">
 <input type="text" value="hello" />
</div>
```

Originally, all this did was to capture click events on the text `hello`, replacing the text with an input box. When the user then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the new text would be saved to server via AJAX and the input box again replaced with just the text.

Now I've added the `a` tag to allow navigation via <kbd>Tab</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than *only* using the mouse (accessibility; yay!), but I'm finding that, when doing so, the call to `focus()` magically triggers the `keyup()` event. (I know this because commenting out the call to `focus()` otherwise results in the desired behaviour.)

The result is that tabbing and entering onto the text opens but then immediately closes the `input` box, and as far as the user's concerned, nothing has happened at all.

Why is the `input`'s `keyup` handler being triggered by a `click` event on a completely unrelated element? How can I stop this from happening?

---

#### Working scenario

1. Click on `hello`
2. `hello` disappears; textbox appears, with caret inside it
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Textbox disappears; `hello` reappears

#### Broken scenario

1. Put focus on document
2. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> until `hello` is in focus
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. `hello` disappears; textbox appears, with caret inside it
5. Textbox disappears; `hello` reappears ... before I have a chance to do anything.

Comment: In your broken scenario, hold down enter on step 3.  It's not until you release it (ie keyup, which is happening on the focussed input) that 4 and 5 happen.  That's the _why_ it's happening, as for fixing it...

Comment: @JamesThorpe: Yeah. :(

Comment: does putting a tabindex on the anchor tag and the input solve anything?

Comment: I was trying to set a flag in the click so that the keyup can check for `if (e.keyCode == 13 && !flag) {` but you only want to set the flag in the click if it was triggered by a keypress, and there doesn't seem to be a reliable method of detecting whether click was fired by the mouse or keyboard...

Comment: I wonder whether http://stackoverflow.com/q/22346903/560648 is the same problem, ultimately.

Comment: doesn't a contenteditable DIV a solution for you? http://jsfiddle.net/7qjcdqzx/

Comment: @A.Wolff Valid point.  Added benefit of the caret going to where you clicked also

Comment: @JamesThorpe: Thanks for your interest BTW :)

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit It was an interesting problem so kept an eye on it - just didn't have time to try anything much myself!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an alternative solution.  The only difference in functionality is that the input only appears and is focused when the enter key is *released*.  It listens to `keydown` and prevents the default keyboard click, and then performs the swap in the `keyup` event instead so that the `keyup` doesn't make it to the input field.  I've tried it in IE 11, Chrome, and Firefox, all on Windows.

```
$(function() {
    $('#edit').hide();

    $('#value')
        .css('cursor', 'pointer')
        .click(function() {
            $('#edit').show();
            $('#edit input').focus();
            $('#value').hide();
         });

    $('#value a')
        .keydown(function(e) { // Prevent default enter click
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
            }
        }).keyup(function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                $('#edit').show();
                $('#edit input').focus();
                $('#value').hide();
            }
        });

    $('#edit input')
        .keyup(function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {  // <enter>
                $('#value').show();
                $('#edit').hide();
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: I was asking on behalf of a colleague and I'm told that this is the one we'll be using, so the accept is yours. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

So the problem is that when you press the enter key, the `keyup` event is fired when you release the key.

This creates a flow like the following:
1, click the link (press enter key)
2, link hides
3, focus is given to text input (enter key is still pressed at this point)
4, release of key (keyup event is fired)

If you change the event to `keydown` then pressing enter on the link will not conflict the input because that input doesn't have focus.

Additionally, using the same code in the keydown event that you had in the keyup event will still do the exact same thing (ie press enter and the input hides and the link shows).

**EDIT**

https://jsfiddle.net/geyut7uv/

The only solid solution that I could find, was to create a "blocker" variable that "disables" the keydown event. I've attached it to the link only when the keydown is clicked. This is checked on the keydown event by the input which will be immediately triggered if a user holds the key down.

It's only when the enter key keyup event is triggered that I allow the "blocker" variable pass.

Ideally, I'd like to remove all global scope variables, but I couldn't find a way to recognize that an event (keydown) was currently in use.

```
<div id="value">
    <a href="#">hello</a>
</div>
<div id="edit">
    <input type="text" value="hello" />
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var enter_enabled = true;
    $('#edit').hide();

    $('#value')
    .css('cursor', 'pointer')
    .click(function() {
        $('#edit').show();
        $('#edit input').focus();
        $('#value').hide();
    }).keydown(function(e){
        enter_enabled = false;
    });

    $('#edit input')
    .keydown(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 13 && enter_enabled){
            $('#value').show();
            $('#edit').hide();
        }
    })
    .keyup(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 13){
            enter_enabled = true;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: If you hold down return for too long, you get repeated keypresses, so the keydown fires on the input, changing it back to the link.

Comment: I think your explanation is spot on. However, I don't think the fix is right.

Comment: I could only achieve the desired results by creating an external variable. I couldn't recognize that an event was already in motion, which is a shame because I feel like that method should exist within JavaScript. I've updated the code to reflect the desired effect.

Comment: Your edit has reproduced the same as one of the other answers now - if you click the link, you now need to hit return twice (or have pressed another key) on the input.  Note that this isn't a global variable - it's contained in the outer function, so in my opinion is fine - it's contained within the scope of this functionality.

Comment: thats strange i only have to hit enter once to hide the input

Comment: Is that after clicking the link, or focussing and pressing enter on the link?  If you click the link, you'll need to hit return twice.

Comment: both. click the link then hit enter. and focus the link hit enter on the link then hit enter on the input

Comment: Perhaps it's my copy of your code - have you got a fiddle/code snippet of it?

Comment: That last edit that moved `enter_enabled = false` into the `keydown` event has fixed it - I think this is a nicer solution now, since it still switches on keydown rather than keyup.

Comment: I may have needed to update the code on SO. It's nice to have the option between keydown and keyup as it really depends on the situation that you may need it.

Comment: Absolutely - they're both viable fixes now with the flexibility of choice :)

Comment: Good stuff, thank you! We went with Josiah's in the end and I haven't checked this solution out in full yet, but I'm sure it's good. :)

Answer (score 2):

I went down the route of using a flag [updated fiddle-again](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonwilczak/fud06f2k/20/):

The html remains the same, but the js changes, a bit.  I added a 'valueClicked' variable and set it to false;  Then, use that as the condition in the keyup, however, after the keyup condition check, i reset the flag.

```
     $(function() { 
var valueClickedFromEnter = false;
$('#edit').hide();
function handleLinkClick(event)
{
         $('#edit').show();
        $('#edit input').focus();
        $('#value').hide();
        valueClickedFromEnter = 
            (event.keyCode && event.keyCode == 13);   
}
$('#value')
    .css('cursor', 'pointer')
    .keydown(handleLinkClick).click(handleLinkClick);

$('#edit input')
    .keyup(function(e) {            
        if (e.keyCode == 13 && !valueClickedFromEnter) {  // <enter>
            $('#value').show();
            $('#edit').hide();
        }
        valueClickedFromEnter = false;
    });
```

});

The idea is that whenever you hit enter from tabbing to the anchor, the flag is set, the keyup checked and then the flag is reset so that on the next enter, the condition passes.  Then, using it normally, the flag is never set so the condition still passes.

Edited:  based on feedback, clientX and clientY are not cross-browser solutions.  I have, instead, used an intermediary function to handle the keydown and click events for the anchor tag, passing the event object through.  This object is then checked for a keycode property, if it is 13, then the flag is toggled.

The extra benefit is that using another key, like space bar, causes the link to toggle, as well, and if the user starts typing, it will go into the input.

Comment: This is exactly what I'd originally tried.  However it breaks using the mouse - ie click the link instead now.  You now need to hit return twice (or have pressed at least one other key) in the input

Comment: This is what I was getting at in my comment on the OP as well though - if there's a way to detect if the click was fired by a keypress rather than the mouse, you can then use that to set the flag (or not), which will solve the problem.

Comment: ok, I updated my answer.  checking the client x and y from the click event will yield whether or not it was an enter click or a mouse click.

Comment: in FF on a mac, I get -141 & -461 for respectively clientX & clientY, so you may want to chenge `===0` to `<=0`, but I'm not sure you can entirely count on that info...

Comment: I did change to === 0, can you check again?  I only have ie and chrome here.

Comment: -141+-461 is still not 0 - ie looks like you really can't rely on `clientX` and `clientY` in all browsers.  So back to the problem of differentiating click from keyboard...

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't determine where the click came from (mouse or keyboard) directly.  I do remember running into something similar in another project.  Let me play a bit more...

Comment: Ok, so I updated, again.  This works for both IE9 and Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than messing with flags and whatnot, I decided to disable the `input` element when not visible. Disabled elements can't receive focus, so theoretically you won't have an issue wherein the Enter key was still coming up while the element was active.

I also explicitly set the focus to the anchor when the Enter key is pressed within the `input` element. This ensures that the focus is no longer on that element before disabling it, which could cause issues.

Note that I've only tested this in Chrome 42 (oh, and FF 36 and IE 11) on Windows 8.1, so YMMV.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#edit').hide();

  var keyupHandler = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) { // <enter>
      $('#value').show().focus();
      $('#edit').hide().find('input').prop('disabled', true);
    }
  };

  var clickHandler = function(e) {
    $('#value').hide();
    $('#edit').show(500, function() {
      $(this).find('input').prop('disabled', false).focus();
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  $('#value').on('click', clickHandler);
  $('#edit').on('keydown', 'input', keyupHandler);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="value">
  <a href="#">hello</a>
</div>
<div id="edit">
  <input type="text" value="hello" />
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Hold the "enter" key down for more than a fraction of a second and the original problem is reproduced!

Comment: It just seems kind of implicit :P

Comment: I guess I don't hold down the Enter key as a matter of course. I tap my keysssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss... For the most part :P

Comment: I'm always trying to think not of what I do, but of what my users will do. :)

Comment: So, how long can they hold the Enter key down? I mean, half a second (as I've added above) seems like an extraordinarily long time to hold down a key.

Answer (score 0):

Updated to fix the long-press issue. Problem is simple, you had an event listening for keyup, you specifically gave focus to that element, so it was triggering when user released the key.

Update #2:
This one should work fully, Ironically, I had to reverse my initial change to execute everything upon element hiding.

Try this:

```
var enterPressed = false;
var enteredExclusion = false;
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#edit').hide();

$('#value')
    .css('cursor', 'pointer')
    .click(function() {
        $('#value').hide();
        $('#edit').show();
            $('#editabletext').focusin(function(e){
                enteredExclusion = true;
            }).focusout(function(e){
                enterPressed = false;
                enteredExclusion = false;
            }).focus();
    });

$('#editabletext')
    .keydown(function(e){
        if (e.keyCode == 13 && !enteredExclusion) {  // <enter>
            console.log('setting true');
            enterPressed = true;
        }
     })
    .keyup(function(e) {
        enteredExclusion = false;
        if (e.keyCode == 13 && (enterPressed  )) {
            $('#value').show();
            $('#edit').hide();
            console.log('setting false - keyup');
            enterPressed = false;
        }
    });
 });
```

html:

```
<div id="value">
    <a href="#">hello</a>
</div>
<div id="edit">
    <input id="editabletext" type="text" value="hello" />
</div>
```

Comment: Hey y'know this isn't bad - results encouraging so far. Could you explain a little how deferring the `focus()` call fixes it?

Comment: This still suffers the "hold the return key for too long" problem - the keyup still fires on the input

Comment: Yeah this is a "works if you get lucky with timing" solution I suppose. At the moment I do think the right approach is swapping `keyUp` for something else so it doesn't "steal" half a keypress from the original element. :)

Comment: This no longer seems to focus the input after the last update?

Answer (score -1):

What is happening seems to be the following:

1) User presses enter on the focused element -> this will trigger the click event as well as the keyup event. The click event is triggered first.

2) Handler of click on `#value` will be called. This handler shows the `#edit` field and sets the focus on this field.

3) The keyup event is triggered. But since the focus now lies on `#edit`, it will be triggered for this field (!)

4) Handler of keyup on `#edit` will be called and hides the `#edit` field again.

Comment: i think this only answers half the question, the "Why", OP also wants the "How to fix" part.

Comment: @JasonWilczak I think that people don't know what the up- and down-voting buttons are for. You vote up if the answer is useful and down if it is not useful. Are you saying that half an answer is not useful? It's better than nothing isn't it? I mean, I get it, it doesn't answer everything. And it's also not that I can't live with a down vote. But still...why? What is the point of down-voting an answer that is correct and addresses the original question (or at least half of it)?

Comment: I mean, i'm not sure.  I didn't downvote your answer since it was on topic, but I didn't upvote it either since it didn't answer the full question.  I agree, if it is on topic and answers part of the question at hand, then a downvote isn't in order, but, obviously, some people feel differently ::shrug::